# Energy conservation in antenna

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, energy-conservation, antennas

When electrons oscillate in antenna the do work against resistance which becomes heat so from where it gets energy to create radiation

Comment: generator connected to the antenna

Answer (score 0):

In general electric circuits need batteries or generators to work. Heat is part of the product , the [drifting electrons](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/miccur.html) in the resistances scatter and change the kinetic energy of the lattices, and thus generate heat.

In alternating currents  part of the current variation goes to the above described heat, and part to electromagnetic radiation because of the acceleration/deceleration cycle forced on the drifting electrons.

In [antennas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antenna_(radio)) this radiation is coherent, the radiation from the lattice electrons of the fermi level generating  an electromagnetic  wave .

In energy conservation all the dissipation sinks have to be added up, from resistances and from radiation.